# how can i decode unicode string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, wikipedia-api

Wikipedia API encodes string into unicode format

```
"Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama"
```

how can i convert it back to

```
"Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture – Drama"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia API returns JSON data, use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to decode:

```
json.loads(inputstring)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.loads('"Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama"')
Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture – Drama
```

If you instead have a string that starts with `u''`, you already *have* a Python unicode value and are looking at the representation of that string:

```
>>> json.loads('"Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama"')
u'Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama'
```

Just *print* that value to have Python encode it to your terminal codec and represent that em-dash character in a format your terminal will understand.

You may want to read up about Python and Unicode and encodings before you continue, if you do not understand what the difference is between a unicode value and byte strings:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: thanks that was helpful,
what i have is
a = u'Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama'

i tried
a = '"'+a+'"'
a = json.loads(a)
ended up with original string, what am i doing wrong, how to replace that \u2013 to -?

thanks in advance

Comment: @ChakradarRaju: Then you *already* have a valid Python unicode string and are looking at the representation. Just print it.

Comment: i'm not going to print it, urllib.quote(u'Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama'), raises this exception KeyError: u'\u2013'

Comment: You need to *encode* that unicode value first before you can use it in  a URL. UTF-8 is usually fine for browsers.

Comment: `urllib.quote(u'Golden Globe Award for Best Motion Picture \u2013 Drama'.encode('utf8'))` works, for example.